# Rails application using mysql - syntax error only with mysql not sqlite?

Tags: php, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I'm very green to `ruby on rails` and have been working on getting an application working with mysql, everything works except for one particular page when loading assets from `mysql` database.

I'm not sure what is going on and have not had luck fixing it.

I'm running on `ubuntu`, with `passenger 4.0.20`, `mysql 2.9.1 gem`, `rails 3.0.7`,

when viewing the page either under the passenger daemon or through strictly apache the app returns this:

`Mysql::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 'assets')' at line 1: SELECT`types`.* FROM`types`WHERE (type_for == 'assets')`

Extracted source (around line #52):

```
49:   </div>
50:   <div class="field">
51:     <%= f.label :asset_type_id %><br />
52:     <%= f.select :asset_type_id, Type.where("type_for == 'assets'").collect{|u| [ u.name, u.id ]} , { :include_blank => true }, {}  %>    
53:   </div>
54:   <div class="field">
55:     <%= f.label :asset_status_id %><br />  

app/views/assets/_form.html.erb:52:in `block in_app_views_assets__form_html_erb___1678548858904611904_30514700_2370109183913626002'
app/views/assets/_form.html.erb:1:in         `_app_views_assets__form_html_erb___1678548858904611904_30514700_2370109183913626002'
app/views/assets/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_assets_new_html_erb___211939086717483877_30551560__3850816556217762359'
```

I'm at my end of possible things to try, not really sure where to go with this. Any help would be amazing right now.

Comment: edit your post clearly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `==` from line 52 and replace with just `=`

```
52:     <%= f.select :asset_type_id, Type.where("type_for = 'assets'").collect{|u| [ u.name, u.id ]} , { :include_blank => true }, {}  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error on this line

```
<%= f.select :asset_type_id, Type.where("type_for == 'assets'").collect{|u| [ u.name, u.id ]} , { :include_blank => true }, {} %>
```

it should be like this

```
<%= f.select :asset_type_id, Type.where("type_for" => "assets").collect{|u| [ u.name, u.id ]} , { :include_blank => true }, {} %>
```

**OR**

you can write it as

```
<%= f.select :asset_type_id, Type.where("type_for = ?", "assets").collect{|u| [ u.name, u.id ]} , { :include_blank => true }, {} %>
```

**OR**

```
<%= f.select :asset_type_id, Type.where(:conditions =>["type_for = ?", "assets"]).collect{|u| [ u.name, u.id ]} , { :include_blank => true }, {} %>
```

And As **@MikeCampbell** pointed,it can also written as

```
<%= f.select :asset_type_id, Type.where("type_for" :"assets").collect{|u| [ u.name, u.id ]} , { :include_blank => true }, {} %>
```

Comment: `"type_for ?"` should be `"type_for = ?"`.

Comment: `"type_for" = "assets"` should be `"type_for" => "assets"` too, or preferably `type_for: "assets"`

Comment: @MikeCampbell Thanks! It is hard to believe i missed that.

Comment: Thanks yeah it was the == vs =. that did the trick. Was looking me right in the face. I'm so glad stackoverflow is a thing.